# Device to vary the AC voltage output and frequency

Tags: microcontroller, ac, adc, function-generator

Can a function generator be used to generate signals from 120 V to 220 V with a frequency of 50 Hz or 60 Hz?

The issue is that I require these signals to test an application for a microcontroller that reads AC signals through an ADC peripheral. I need to do tests by varying the voltage and frequency input.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to do this is to hook an audio amplifier up to your function generator, and then feed the signal from the amplifier into a transformer. The audio amp provides the necessary power to drive the transformer, and the latter then steps the voltage up to the desired level.

You can use a standard 230V mains transformer in reverse (i.e. a 12V model).

Keep in mind that this is just as dangerous as real mains voltage.